# Array_unique gives a php error when applied on array_merge()

Tags: php

I have two arrays which I merge using:

$query = array_merge($query1, $query2);

After merging I want to apply array unique:

$query = array_unique($query);

For some reason it gives me a php error, a page black.

**I suspect it's because of the structure of the array's that need merging.**

A vardump illustrates the structure of query1 and query 2:

```
array(73) { 
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#32 (6) { 
        ["pic0"]=> string(78) "the picture1 link" 
        ["bio"]=> string(22)  "the bio1" 
    } 
    [1]=> object(stdClass)#96 (6) { 
        ["pic0"]=> string(70) "the picture2 link" 
        ["bio"]=> string(225) "the bio2" 
    } 
 }
```

Comment: "For some reason it gives me a php error" --- is it that game when we need to guess the actual error message? "I suspect" --- the fact is - programming is a precise thing, we don't care of suspects, we care of facts.

Comment: So what error did it give you?  A blank page is hardly an error.  It usually hints to an error somewhere...

Comment: Yes a black page, let me try editing the question. So you are saying the array structure is ok for the array_unique function to work? So i should look elsewhere?

Comment: Wait... a **black** page?  Not a *blank* page? I'm confused...

Comment: Black page? :-S Are you sure your monitor is turned on? PS: have you checked error logs?

Comment: @zerkms To be honest, you don't actually need to know the error to solve this problem.

Comment: @Kolink: if you don't teach people how to ask questions properly - you will always waste your time by interrogating them about the details. And this question is just a rare exception, when the answer is obvious from the code and dump.

Comment: @Kolink you are right, sorry for the unclear question and I'll try my best to ask better ones in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_unique` works by comparing the elements as strings. Objects generally can't be converted to strings, so you are getting an error.

Try using arrays instead of `stdClass`es, and also make sure you set the `SORT_REGULAR` flag.

Comment: Ty very much, got it :) - but I am afraid I cannot do this because $query is a mysql query result using wordpress get_results() which returns stdClasses. $query = $wpdb->get_results(mysql query);

Comment: I merged two arrays containing query results and I wanted to eliminate the uniques

Comment: Try adding the `SORT_REGULAR` flag and see if that works. I don't know how object comparison works (or if it works at all), but it's worth a shot.